# Can't change posts per page in WordPress Post Type Query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, query-posts

I have a custom post type called "Events". The post displays fine, except that the WP Query loop only displays one post instead of all of them. Here is the complete code from my functions.php file for Events:

```
    function min_get_events ( $echo = true ) {
     $events = new WP_query(array(
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'min_event-start',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key'     => 'min_event-start',
        'value'   => date('Y-m-d'),
        'compare' => '>',
    )
));

$i = 0;
$n = 1;

if ( $events->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $events->have_posts() ):
        global $post;
        $events->the_post();

        $open_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'min_event-start', true);
        $close_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'min_event-end', true);
        $start = strtotime($open_date);
        $end = strtotime($close_date);
        if ($start==$end || $start > $end) {
            $date_string = date('F j, Y', $start);
        }
        else {
            $date_string = date('F j, Y', $start) .' &ndash; '. date('F j, Y', $end);
        }
        //$description = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event-description', true);
        $location = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'min_event-location', true);
        $url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'min_event-url', true);
        //$registration_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event-registration-url', true);
        $cta_text = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'min_event-cta-text', true);
        $cta = !empty($cta_text) ? $cta_text : 'Register Now';

        $i++;
        if ( $i == 1 ) {
            ?>
            <div class="row">
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <div class="event col-sm-4">
            <a href="<?= $url ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumb-events'); ?>
            </a>
            <h1><?= htmlentities($post->post_title) ?></h1>
            <div >
                <div><?= $date_string; ?></div>
                <div><?= htmlentities($location) ?></div>
                <div><a href="<?=$url;?>" class="register-now"><?= $cta; ?></a></div>
            </div>
            <!-- <p><?= $description ?></p> -->
            <!-- <p><a href="<?=$url;?>" class="register-now"><?= $cta; ?></a></p> -->
        </div> <!-- .event -->
        <?php


        if ( $i == 3  || ($events->current_post +1) == $events->post_count) {
            ?>
            </div> <!-- <?php echo $i; ?> .row <?php echo $n; ?> -->
            <?php
            $i = 0;
            $n++;
        }

    endwhile;
endif;

ob_start();
?>

<?php
$return = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
wp_reset_postdata();
if ( $echo ) {
    echo $return;
} else {
    return $return;
}
 }
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you sure the query returns more than one post?

Comment: @cjbj it's only returning 1 post. There's currently 9 posts for that post type

Comment: Do you get 4 results if you set `posts_per_page` param to 4?  The purpose is to determine if that param is affecting your query at all.  A `pre_get_posts` hook somewhere might be limiting your result as well?

Comment: @jdm2112 it still only gives me 1 post. Hmmm let me check for that

Comment: @jdm2112 just checked for pre_get_posts not in the code anywhere

Comment: In that posttype. perhaps. But you're also checking against a date.

Comment: Try dumping `$events` right after instantiating WP_Query.  What is your `found_posts` value?

Comment: just did that and got this: int(1) @jdm2112

Answer (score 1):

The meta_query parameter must be change in an array of array for a single custom field handling:

```
 'meta_query' => array(
     array(
         'key'     => 'min_event-start',
         'value'   => date('Y-m-d'),
         'compare' => '>',
    )
 )
```

You will the informations [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) in the Single Custom field handling part

Hope it will work with this.

Comment: Good catch.  Didn't notice this.  Meta query is an array of arrays.